# Symfony2: prod in a chroot environment?

Tags: php, symfony, fastcgi, freebsd

As a learning exercise I used Symfony to update an existing application for a local non-profit. Development was in a Windows environment.  Now that the application has been installed on their ISP's shared host I start to learn about chroot on a FastCGI server.  There are errors such as this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with
>   message 'The stream or file
>   "/home/projectmana/www2.projectmana.org/app/logs/prod.log" could not
>   be opened: failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in
>   /www2.projectmana.org/app/cache/prod/classes.php:4823

The ISP responds with:

> Bad path.  PHP is chrooted in /home/projectmana/.

OK. I get it that this is the problem. Web searches so far have not provided a clue as to how to proceed. (I've gained greater appreciation for Symfony wanting to avoid shared hosting.) Is there a solution that I, a relative novice and a volunteer, can implement in my code, or does the application have to find a new home?

Comment: @akluth: Now I'm more befuddled.  I went thru all of that yesterday and still had problems. Now everything appears to work but for a route that takes a parameter - results in a 401.  I saw this yesterday - that's when I went back to clear cache, etc.  And started getting the error above.  Perhaps the problem is incorrectly stated.

Comment: @akluth: Just confirmed - clearing cache, forcing `chmod -R 777` on cache and logs brings back above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in this instance was to override the locations of the cache and logs directories [according to the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html). This, however, by itself causes the `cache:clear` command to fail. The answer to that problem will have to appear in another question if I can't find it on my own.

#### Update

The other solution here cannot work because any php setting in .htaccess when Apache server is running FastCGI will cause a server error.  Clearing the cache was never solved so the site was moved to a non-CGI host.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to set the `doc_root` variable according to your chrooted directory:

```
doc_root = "/home/projectmana"
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0
```

You do this in the php.ini file - which seems to be not an option for you since you're on a shared server environment. When using Apache as a webserver, you can use a `.htaccess` file and set the proper PHP directives there via `php_value`.

Comment: Since neither php.ini or Apache are available, I experimented with overriding logs & cache directories per symfony's configuration cookbook.  This seems to solve all but the route problem.  That's next up.

Comment: Comment re: htscanner deleted.  Requires administrative access; not for end user/developer.